# Ruby CSV converter, remove all converters?

Tags: ruby, date, parsing, csv, converters

I have some data I was writing from one CSV to another CSV because I need to do some data manipulation.

I noticed the CSV library has some default converters that are taking my values that look like dates and parsing those into new date strings.

I was wondering if I could remove all converters? I tried using my custom converter, but no matter what I do it seems that the dates keep getting parsed.

Here is my code simplified:

```
require 'csv'

CSV::Converters[:my_converter] = lambda do |value|
    value
end

CSV.open('new-data.csv', 'w') do |csv|
    data = CSV.read('original-data.csv', :converters => [:my_converter]).each do |row|
        csv << row
    end
end
```

The value `9/30/14 0:00` is getting changed to `9/30/2014 0:00`, for example.

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using? What does the example source file look like? Are you sure the file doesn't really contain 2014?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question concerning data, it's critical you provide the minimal example data necessary to duplicate the problem. Without that, and the required output format, we're left guessing what the problem is. Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your CSV file doesn't actually contain the 4-digit year? Try looking at `puts File.read('original-data.csv')`

When I tried this on Ruby 2.1.8, it didn't change the value

```
require 'csv'

my_csv_data = 'hello,"9/30/14 0:00",world'

CSV.new(my_csv_data).each do |row|
  puts row.inspect # prints ["hello", "9/30/14 0:00", "world"], as expected
end
```

Comment: Crap you're right! :facepalm: The original did have 2014. The records that I was comparing to had been touched by excel, for some reason I'm guessing excel did the formatting of 2014 to 14.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files are not parsed and converted into objects, the data in the fields is returned as a string. Always. This behavior is different than YAML or JSON, which do convert back to their base types.

Consider this:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.parse("1,10/1/14,foo") # => [["1", "10/1/14", "foo"]]
```

All values are strings.

```
csv = ["foo", 'bar', 1, Date.new(2014, 10, 1)].to_csv # => "foo,bar,1,2014-10-01\n"
```

Converting an array containing native Ruby objects results in a string of comma-delimited values.

```
CSV.parse(csv) # => [["foo", "bar", "1", "2014-10-01"]]
```

Reparsing that string returns the string versions but doesn't attempt to return them to their original types as CSV doesn't have a way of knowing what those were. The developer (you) has to know and do that.

The end-result of all that is that CSV won't change a year from '14' to '2014'. It doesn't know that it's a date, and, because it's not CSV's place to convert to objects, it only splits the fields appropriately and passes the information on to be massaged by the developer.

Comment: "The data in the fields is returned as a string. Always" - except if the value is empty, which will return nil